# How to set gradient background on windows

Tags: windows, colors

Is it possible to set gradient desktop background on windows 8.1 in `Personalization` -> `Desktop Background`?
I see only solid colors to choose.
How can I do this

Comment: Create a wallpaper with the gradient you want and use the wallpaper.

Comment: I know this method

Comment: If you know how to do it what isn't satisfactory about this approach?

Comment: I thought I can only select gradient color and apply but if it is not possible so I create wallpaper I'm just curious about this

Comment: @Seth the unsatisfactory part is that when a gradient wallpaper is used, it doesn't resize if you swap the monitor or change the resolution. With a color gradient, whatever size your screen is in pixels, it just re-adjusts.

Like when having a laptop and moving between docks that have different screens attached.

Comment: Set the wallpaper to stretch and aside from screens that have a much higher resolution (assuming you keep the aspect ratio) you should not have any issues. Up until Windows 10 (to the best of my knowledge) there is no native support for this. Additional software might help you out but probably will just generate a wallpaper with a suiting dimension.